# Ошибка ReferenceError: Can't find variable: createPagination как исправить?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, pagination

При вызове функции **createPagination** в файле main.js - получаю ошибку **Can't find variable: createPagination**.

модуль pagination.js:

```js
const element = document.querySelector(".pagination ul");

function createPagination(totalPages, page) {
  let liTag = "";
  let active;
  let beforePage = page - 1;
  let afterPage = page + 1;
  if (page > 1) {
    //show the next button if the page value is greater than 1
    liTag += `<li class="btn prev" onclick="createPagination(${totalPages}, ${
            page - 1
        })"><span><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> Prev</span></li>`;
  }

  if (page > 2) {
    //if page value is less than 2 then add 1 after the previous button
    liTag += `<li class="first numb" onclick="createPagination(${totalPages}, 1)"><span>1</span></li>`;
    if (page > 3) {
      //if page value is greater than 3 then add this (...) after the first li or page
      liTag += `<li class="dots"><span>...</span></li>`;
    }
  }

  // how many pages or li show before the current li
  if (page == totalPages) {
    beforePage = beforePage - 2;
  } else if (page == totalPages - 1) {
    beforePage = beforePage - 1;
  }
  // how many pages or li show after the current li
  if (page == 1) {
    afterPage = afterPage + 2;
  } else if (page == 2) {
    afterPage = afterPage + 1;
  }

  for (var plength = beforePage; plength <= afterPage; plength++) {
    if (plength > totalPages) {
      //if plength is greater than totalPage length then continue
      continue;
    }
    if (plength == 0) {
      //if plength is 0 than add +1 in plength value
      plength = plength + 1;
    }
    if (page == plength) {
      //if page is equal to plength than assign active string in the active variable
      active = "active";
    } else {
      //else leave empty to the active variable
      active = "";
    }
    liTag += `<li class="numb ${active}" onclick="createPagination(${totalPages}, ${plength})"><span>${plength}</span></li>`;
  }

  if (page < totalPages - 1) {
    //if page value is less than totalPage value by -1 then show the last li or page
    if (page < totalPages - 2) {
      //if page value is less than totalPage value by -2 then add this (...) before the last li or page
      liTag += `<li class="dots"><span>...</span></li>`;
    }
    liTag += `<li class="last numb" onclick="createPagination(${totalPages}, ${totalPages})"><span>${totalPages}</span></li>`;
  }

  if (page < totalPages) {
    //show the next button if the page value is less than totalPage(20)
    liTag += `<li class="btn next" onclick="createPagination(${totalPages}, ${
            page + 1
        })"><span>Next <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span></li>`;
  }
  element.innerHTML = liTag; //add li tag inside ul tag
  return liTag; //return the li tag
}

export default createPagination;
```

main.js:

```js
import "./style.css";
let {
  default: createPagination
} = await
import ("./modules/pagination.js");

const element = document.querySelector(".pagination ul");
let totalPages = 5;
let page = 2;

//calling function with passing parameters and adding inside element which is ul tag
element.innerHTML = createPagination(totalPages, page);
```

index.html

```html
<!-- <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html> -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pagination in JavaScript </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/47cad546ff.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/main.js" defer></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul>
      <!--pages or li are comes from javascript -->
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #20B2AA;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pagination ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.pagination ul li {
  color: #20B2AA;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.pagination ul li.numb {
  list-style: none;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pagination ul li.numb.first {
  margin: 0px 3px 0 -5px;
}

.pagination ul li.numb.last {
  margin: 0px -5px 0 3px;
}

.pagination ul li.dots {
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: default;
}

.pagination ul li.btn {
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.pagination li.active,
.pagination ul li.numb:hover,
.pagination ul li:first-child:hover,
.pagination ul li:last-child:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #20B2AA;
}
```

Проблема исправляется решением:
**window.createPagination = function createPagination(totalPages, page)**
но это использование глобальной переменной - что само по себе не хорошо...
Какие есть варианты решения - подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `export default function createPagination(totalPages, page) {`

Comment: абсолютно ничего не меняет и не отличается от export default createPagination в конце модуля...